# Correct SQL syntax ( PHP and MySQL Combo)

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, conditional-statements

i have this query :

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT(CT.FIRSTNAME,' ', CT.LASTNAME) AS NAME,
   T.TYPE_OF_VISITOR_NAME AS TYPE_OF_VISITOR,
   I.INDUSTRY_NAME AS INDUSTRY
FROM 
   COMPANY CY, CONTACTS CT, INDUSTRY I, TYPE_OF_VISITOR T
WHERE
   CY.INDUSTRY_ID = I.INDUSTRY_ID
 AND CY.COMPANY_ID = CT.COMPANY_ID
 AND CT.TYPE_OF_VISITOR = T.TYPE_OF_VISITOR_ID
 AND '$searchType' LIKE '%$searchString%'
```

where `$searchType`  is a value from a combo box which contains 2 values :

- NAME (this is not recognized in the database as long as i use  `CONCAT(CT.FIRSTNAME,' ', CT.LASTNAME)` the problem is that when user picked `COMPANY_NAME` i will have wrong syntax)
- COMPANY_NAME

and `$searchString` is an input box for search.

in the query above. when user searches for anything under COMPANY_NAME type it works. the problem is that i want to have a search option also for name(first name and last name). unfortunately the columns in my database is `FIRSTNAME` and `LASTNAME`. which i concatenated in the select statement.

Question :

- What is the right way to achieve the search for `FIRSTNAME` and `LASTNAME` without affecting the result when user wants to search for `COMPANY_NAME`

As much as possible i want to do this using one query only. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `NAME`, the combo box value should be

```
CONCAT(`CT`.`FIRSTNAME`,' ', `CT`.`LASTNAME`)
```

combo box values :

```
1. CONCAT(`CT`.`FIRSTNAME`,' ', `CT`.`LASTNAME`)
2. `COMPANY_NAME`
```

Comment: imagine user seeing `"CONCAT(CT.FIRSTNAME,' ', CT.LASTNAME)"`. They will freak out.

Comment: Otherwise we can write a condition like:

if($searchType == 'NAME'){ $searchType = "CONCAT(CT.FIRSTNAME,' ', CT.LASTNAME)"; }

SELECT 
   CONCAT(CT.FIRSTNAME,' ', CT.LASTNAME) AS NAME,
   T.TYPE_OF_VISITOR_NAME AS TYPE_OF_VISITOR,
   I.INDUSTRY_NAME AS INDUSTRY
FROM 
   COMPANY CY, CONTACTS CT, INDUSTRY I, TYPE_OF_VISITOR T
WHERE
   CY.INDUSTRY_ID = I.INDUSTRY_ID
 AND CY.COMPANY_ID = CT.COMPANY_ID
 AND CT.TYPE_OF_VISITOR = T.TYPE_OF_VISITOR_ID
 AND '$searchType' LIKE '%$searchString%'